# Angular Material Tooltip not showing inside of a div with ng-if

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

So my code looks like this.

```
<div *ngIf="shouldShowSessionWarning()">
   <i class="fas fa-exclamation-triangle fa-lg"
   matTooltip="{{'product_review.uneven_requests_error' | translate}}"
   matTooltipPosition="above"></i>
</div>
```

When `shouldShowSessionWarning()` returns true, the icon shows, but the tooltip is not visible. I've tried similar approaches with [hidden], but the result is still the same.

It's worth noting that the tooltip appears normally when I remove *ngIf.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Can you maybe create a reproduction example on stackblitz?

Comment: You can try  instead *ngIf `<div [style.display]="!shouldShowSessionWarning():'none':null">`. I'm not pretty sure, but I think that the problem can happens because this "|translate", and use a normal way to matToolTip: `[matTooltip]="'product_review.uneven_requests_error' | translate"`